# Dynamic file type icon

Tags: delphi, dynamic, icons

I want to register a file type in windows and make a program with Delphi to draw the icon of file according to its contents (something like a custom icon format). How can I do this?

Comment: Start here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377513(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Better here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc144122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Nortd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749775/nortd) and [user539484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539484/user539484) comments, I searched the internet for "shell icon handler Delphi" and found a good sample [here](http://users.atw.hu/delphicikk/listaz.php?id=696&oldal=11), and also [Shell+ components](http://www.shellplus.com/) has a component to do this.